# sales tracker return cost from query

Tags: oracle, plsql, return-value, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 4.1.1 to build a sales tracker. To explain things as simple as possible we have a table CALLED "CARS" of all products and their cost with the columns as "CAR" and "COST" there are about 500 cars listed and their associated costs.

We have a form setup so the sales staff can record their sales week by week. Simple form with a list of values built upon the "cars" column called "P2_CARS and I want the cost field in the form "P2_COST" to be generated from a query that runs against the table.

It will run dynamically when they change the value in P2_CARS and I have this but pretty sure its all around the wrong way or just wrong.

```
SELECT COST FROM CARS WHERE CARS=P2_CARS
```

can anyone help?

Comment: your sql query is wrong use SELECT COST FROM CARS WHERE CARS = :P2_CARS one question what is CARS in WHERE clause. and if you want to cost of no of cars then use sum(COST) in Query.

Comment: I managed to get this sorted quite quickly. I needed to use:

SELECT COST FROM CARS WHERE CARS = :P2_CARS

also had to change the drop down LOV to show the product as the display and value. So that it would reference it. COST is the column in CARS table and CARS is the corresponding column meaning that whatever the dropdown list showed (:P2_CARS) it would return the COST for it.

Was essentially missing the : in front of the table field

Thanks for your help though

Comment: means P2_CARS Contains multiple value then your query is wrong look at https://community.oracle.com/message/12543719#12543719 for check how to pass colon separated valus to report hope this helps